# How to read kafka statestore in processor which was updated from a different processor?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I have created 2 kafka statestores corresponding to 2 different topics as below.

```
    StateStoreSupplier tempStore1 = Stores.create("tempStore1").withKeys(Serdes.String()).withValues(valueSerde).persistent().build();

    StateStoreSupplier tempStore2 = Stores.create("tempStore2").withKeys(Serdes.String()).withValues(valueSerde).persistent().build();


    streamsBuilder.addSource("Source", "tempTopic1", "tempTopic2")
                    .addProcessor("Process", () -> new Processor(), "Source")
                    .connectProcessorAndStateStores("Process", "tempStore1", "tempStore2")
                    .addStateStore(tempStore1, "Process")
                    .addStateStore(tempStore2, "Process");
```

In the Processor class, I'm able to read and add records to the StatesStores when there's a message in respective topics. But I'm unable to read the store tempStore1 when there's a message coming from tempTopic2 and vice verca.
I have to compare the messages from one statestore to the other, which means I need to read both the state stores.

Here's the sample code snipper from process method. I believe the ProcessorContext(context variable) is different for respective topics and hence the other store is not being accessible.

```
    tempKeyValueStore1 = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore("tempStore1");
            tempKeyValueStore2 = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore("tempStore2");
            if(context.topic().equals("tempTopic1"))
            {
                tempKeyValueStore1.put(value.getHeader().getCorrelationId(), value);
            }else if(context.topic().equals("tempTopic2"))
            {
                tempKeyValueStore2.put(value.getHeader().getCorrelationId(), value);
                System.out.println("Size: "+tempKeyValueStore1.approximateNumEntries()); // returning as 0 although there records in that statestore
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried getting the stores from the context inside of `init()` and setting them as properties on the `Processor` class which you can access during `#process()`? During `init()` the stores you get from the context are not tired to any particular topic. (Actually, I was unaware of the behavior you describe at all... it's interesting you'd get different stores depending on which topic you're processing. Is that correct?)

Comment: I am wondering how you code is running in the first place. You should get an exception because you need to add the stores before you can connect them to the processor...

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your response.
Yes, I'm using context inside init() to retrieve the statestores as below.

tempKeyValueStore1 = (KeyValueStore<String, Object>) context.getStateStore("tempStore1");

tempKeyValueStore2 = (KeyValueStore<String, Object>) context.getStateStore("tempStore2");

Comment: Hi Matt, yes, I have updated the code to add the stores first but copied the old code here mistakenly.